# Airflow, calling dags from a dag causes duplicate dagruns

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the below "Master" DAG.
I want to call the associated DAGs as per the downstream section at the bottom.

However, what happens, is that the first DAG gets called four times, and the other three runs for a microsecond (Not enough to actually perform) and everything comes back green.

How do I get to behave in the direction the downstream section means?

```
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from datetime import datetime

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 12, 29),
    'email': ['email@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
}

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='Offrs_People_Master_V1',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
)

Ingest_People = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ',
    trigger_dag_id='Offrs_People_Ingestion',
    dag=dag
)

Ingest_DataFinder = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='API_DataFinder_Lookup_Ingestion_V1',
    trigger_dag_id='Offrs_People_Ingestion',
    dag=dag
)

Ingest_EmailOversight = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='API_Emailoversight_Lookup_Ingestion_V1',
    trigger_dag_id='Offrs_People_Ingestion',
    dag=dag
)

Publish_People = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='Publise_PE_and_PP_to_MSSQL_DB3',
    trigger_dag_id='Offrs_People_Ingestion',
    dag=dag
)

Ingest_People >> [Ingest_DataFinder, Ingest_EmailOversight] >> Publish_People
```

Thanks.

### Log for first task (Ingest_People):

```
*** Reading remote log from gs://airflowlogs/Offrs_People_Master_V1/Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ/2020-01-04T00:00:00+00:00/1.log.
*** Previous log discarded: 404 GET https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/airflowlogs/o/Offrs_People_Master_V1%2FIngest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ%2F2020-01-04T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00%2F1.log?alt=media: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)

[2020-01-05 00:00:08,693] {taskinstance.py:620} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Offrs_People_Master_V1.Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ 2020-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-01-05 00:00:08,726] {taskinstance.py:620} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Offrs_People_Master_V1.Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ 2020-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-01-05 00:00:08,727] {taskinstance.py:838} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-01-05 00:00:08,727] {taskinstance.py:839} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-01-05 00:00:08,727] {taskinstance.py:840} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-01-05 00:00:08,796] {taskinstance.py:859} INFO - Executing <Task(TriggerDagRunOperator): Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ> on 2020-01-04T00:00:00+00:00
[2020-01-05 00:00:08,796] {base_task_runner.py:133} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'Offrs_People_Master_V1', 'Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ', '2020-01-04T00:00:00+00:00', '--job_id', '43858', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/Offrs_People_MASTER.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmp7of6dc4i']
[2020-01-05 00:00:12,421] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 43858: Subtask Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ [2020-01-05 00:00:12,411] {settings.py:213} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=14172
[2020-01-05 00:00:13,193] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 43858: Subtask Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ [2020-01-05 00:00:13,192] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2020-01-05 00:00:15,011] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 43858: Subtask Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ [2020-01-05 00:00:15,006] {dagbag.py:90} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/airflow/dags/Offrs_People_MASTER.py
[2020-01-05 00:00:15,221] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 43858: Subtask Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ [2020-01-05 00:00:15,221] {cli.py:516} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: Offrs_People_Master_V1.Ingest_People_PE_and_PP_Into_GBQ 2020-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-pipeline.c.mother-216719.internal
[2020-01-05 00:00:15,386] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2020-01-05 00:00:15,386[0m] {[34mdagbag.py:[0m90} INFO[0m - Filling up the DagBag from [1m/home/airflow/airflow/dags/Offrs_People_Ingestion.py[0m[0m
[2020-01-05 00:00:17,353] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/gcs_to_bq.py:185: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator (task_id: OffrsPE_GCS_to_GBQ_Raw). Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'soft_fail': True}
  super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
[2020-01-05 00:00:17,354] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/gcs_to_bq.py:185: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator (task_id: OffrsPP_GCS_to_GBQ_Raw). Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'soft_fail': True}
  super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
[2020-01-05 00:00:17,354] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py:210: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated parameter `bql` used in Task id: Set_PeopleEmail_Staging. Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Airflow.
  category=DeprecationWarning)
[2020-01-05 00:00:17,355] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py:210: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated parameter `bql` used in Task id: Set_PeoplePhone_Staging. Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Airflow.
  category=DeprecationWarning)
[2020-01-05 00:00:17,355] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py:210: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated parameter `bql` used in Task id: Set_PeopleEmail. Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Airflow.
  category=DeprecationWarning)
[2020-01-05 00:00:17,355] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py:210: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated parameter `bql` used in Task id: Set_PeoplePhone. Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Airflow.
  category=DeprecationWarning)
[2020-01-05 00:00:18,623] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2020-01-05 00:00:18,622[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m172} WARNING[0m - State of this instance has been externally set to [1msuccess[0m. Taking the poison pill.[0m
[2020-01-05 00:00:18,631] {helpers.py:307} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 14172
[2020-01-05 00:00:18,673] {helpers.py:285} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=14172, status='terminated') (14172) terminated with exit code -15
[2020-01-05 00:00:18,674] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2020-01-05 00:00:18,674[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m105} INFO[0m - Task exited with return code 0[0m
```

Comment: Can you post your logs?

Comment: since the dag has four tasks, here's the log for the first one.  This task duplicates as well.  figure if i can fix this....maybe I can fix all

Comment: Looks like you're triggering the same DAG four times?

Comment: As @joeb has mentioned, you have created 4 distincts tasks that all trigger the _same_ DAG. Is there a specific reason why you are laying out your data pipeline like this? If your goal is to trigger 4 _distinct_ DAGs, you will have to specify what those dags are with the trigger_dag_id field. Otherwise, it looks like your master DAG is doing precisely what you instructed it to do.

Comment: ok.  now that I've removed the dummy from my head.....can you please tell me how to tell a TriggerRunDagOperator to wait until other DAG is finished?  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might actually want a `SubDagOperator`, which will treat a secondary DAG as a task to be waited on before continuing.

Comment: @joeb.  do you have any examples.  it seems all the documentation I look at are either class definitions, or impossible examples to follow.  help?  thanks.

Comment: @joeb.  I need you to create an answer so I can give you the bounty.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TriggerDagRun` is more of a "fire and forget" operation and from your comments it sounds like you might actually want a `SubDagOperator`, which will treat a secondary DAG as a task to be waited on before continuing.